# Forward mouse events from JList to the items in the list

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist

Currently, I have a `Jlist` with a custom `CellRenderer` as follows. I attached a custom `MouseListener` in order to capture hover events and, later on, double click events; but the events weren't being fired when I added them this way. After 20 minutes, I found out it was because the `JList` was blocking the events from reaching the individual list items. Is there any way I can force the `JList` to forward the mouse events to its children elements, or is there a better way of doing this.

My CellRenderer:

```
public class FriendRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus) {

        Friend friend = (Friend)value;

        JLabel label = new JLabel(friend.getName());

        JPanel mainOuterPanel = new JPanel();
        mainOuterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        /* Adding components to mainOuterPanel... */

        /* Here is where I add the custom MouseListener */
        mainOuterPanel.addMouseListener(new ListItemMouseListener());

        return(mainOuterPanel);
    }

}
```

My MouseListener:

```
public class ListItemMouseListener implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        Component source = e.getComponent();
        source.setBackground(new Color(102, 99, 86));
        System.out.println("Mouse entered on " + source.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        Component source = e.getComponent();
        source.setBackground(null);
        System.out.println("Mouse Exited on " + source.toString());
    }
}
```

Where I build my JList in my JFrame:

```
private JList getFriendsList(){
    friendsList = new JList(getFriendsListModel()); //TODO Actually fill with data
    friendsList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    friendsList.setLayoutOrientation( JList.VERTICAL );
    friendsList.addListSelectionListener(new FriendsListSelectionListener());
    friendsList.setCellRenderer(new FriendRenderer());
    return friendsList;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side-note: try avoiding to create new `Component`s in the `getListCellRendererComponent` method. It is better to adjust an existing component and return that same component over and over again

Comment: So, do you suggest I create like a template in the constructor and just modify that and return it each time? Sorry if i'm misunderstanding, i'm new to coding swing layouts by hand.

Comment: That is exactly what I am suggesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the listener to the list and use the list methods to convert the point to a row.

The reason it is not working when added to the renderer, is that the render is really only used for ..rendering.  It is like a 'template' used to paint the list item (& every other visible list item) before the item(s) appear on-screen.

---

> ..access the cells .. in order to change the background..

Configure the [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to handle that.

Comment: @Brandon not sure in this case, not deepest knowledges about `JList` (hate this one, using `JTable` instead of), if (for example) `JToolTip` corretly firing events from `JList` but without any issue from `JTable` (`JTable` with one `Column` and/or without `JTableHeader`)

Comment: That's right, I think i've seen that somewhere. How though do I access the cells layout in order to change the background from the listener on the JList? I can't find any method for that in the jlist interface.

Comment: @mKorbel If I can't get this to work easily then I might just end up doing that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how the TreeCellRenderer will help me change the list items background...